# R: subscript out of bounds in tbl_spark when checking its length

Tags: r, group-by, sparklyr

I am new to `sparklyr` library in R and I am starting to play with `library(nycflights13)`, but I am having a problem with my data-frame each time I try to calculate a result from it. Here is what I am doing:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local', version = '2.4.0')

fly <- sdf_copy_to(sc, flights, overwrite = TRUE)
fly %>% tally()
```

When I run this code the console prints `` Error in regexpr("`", x)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds ``. I checked the `tally()` function to see if it is a problem of it but the same error appears when I run a command like `fly %>% summarize(delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))` to calculate the mean of a column.

However, if I do a `group_by` first the error is gone and the output is what I expected:

```
> fly %>% group_by(origin) %>% tally()
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  origin      n
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 JFK    111279
2 EWR    120835
3 LGA    104662

> fly %>% group_by(origin) %>% summarize(delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  origin delay
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 JFK     12.1
2 EWR     15.1
3 LGA     10.3
```

So, I deduce the problem arises when the output is a single number. What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has to do with the last version of `tidyverse`, which raises these errors. An alternative to `tally()` is `sdf_nrow()`, and an alternative to `summarize(mean())` is `sdf_describe()`:

```
> fly %>% sdf_nrow()
[1] 336776

> fly %>% sdf_describe(cols = 'dep_delay')
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  summary dep_delay         
  <chr>   <chr>             
1 count   328521            
2 mean    12.639070257304708
3 stddev  40.21006089212968 
4 min     -43.0             
5 max     1301.0
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.4.0/topics/sdf_dim
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.4.0/topics/sdf_describe